# Writing Scripts For Android

Tags: applications

So I recently downloaded ScriptRunner for android and was wanting to learn how write a basic script to open an app click at a certain x y coordinate and perhaps take a screen capture at a given time. So if anybody could get me started in the right direction id very much appreciate it.

Comment: There are a number of apps with "ScriptRunner" in the name. You should [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/237035/edit) your post to include a link to the website/Google Play Store page. Also it would help to know if you intend to run scripts on a rooted device or not.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at UI Automator https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator

If you want just something very simple, you could create a shell script with adb commands instead. E.g.:

Click on coordinate 500, 500:

```
adb shell input tap 500 500
```

Launch an app:

```
adb shell am start com.package.name
```

Take screenshot:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
```

Comment: So with those commands do I need a hash bang first if I'm using script runner for these particular commands?

Comment: What is this script runner you're talking about?

Comment: it was this scripting app I download but this UI automator you speak of is that also a scripting app for android although I can't seem to find it in the App Store